# In Bowen theory, what is the different between Emotion and Feeling

Tags: emotion

I'm reading Family Evaluation and Bowen/Kerr keep referring to Emotion and Feeling. Those seem like the same thing to me, so I'm wondering what the difference is between them.

Example:
"Objectivity and the associated autonomy from one's environment derive from the capacity to recognize the difference between emotional, feeling, subjective and objective responses and to act based on that recognition."

Obviously "objective", "subjective" and "emotional" are distinct concepts, but how is "feeling" different than "emotional"?

Comment: Great question.  Welcome to Psychology.SE